# java aws cdk Cannot find the 'jsii-runtime' executable

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to use the AWS CDK for the first time.

I'm getting the following error when building my java app

```
Cannot find the 'jsii-runtime' executable
```

**Maven Depencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdk-cloudformation-include</artifactId>
    <version>1.79.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.jsii/jsii-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.jsii</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsii-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.79.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java Code**

```
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Stack;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.StackProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.cloudformation.include.CfnInclude;

public class MyStack extends Stack {
    public MyStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public MyStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        CfnInclude template = CfnInclude.Builder.create(this, "Template")
            .templateFile("/home/vmdovs/NetBeansProjects/cf-import/yaml2/ubuntu16.04LTS_cfn-hup.yaml")
            .build();
       
    }
}


  public void testawscdk() {
    App app = new App();

    new MyStack(app, "MyStack");
}
```

Let me know your thoughts
Regards Conteh

Comment: Hi, I would recommend to not mix cdk versions (1.76.0 and 1.77.0) in the dependencies. The jsii error is quite unspecified... could you check that node is installed and on PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was that AWS CDK was not installed

The following installation script resolved the problem

```
apt-get install python3-pip -y

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --config python

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1
sudo update-alternatives --config pip

pip install aws-cdk.cdk

pip install awscli

export PATH=/home/vagrant/.local/bin:$PATH

echo "export PATH=/home/vagrant/.local/bin:$PATH" >> .bashrc

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

node --version

sudo npm install -g aws-cdk
```